# Como enviar um vetor Javascript para o php e exibi-los?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Eu consigo criar o meu array javascript e armazeno os valores dentro de um array chamado `ArmazenaIds`

```
ArmazenaIds = new Array();
    $('.checkboxs').each(function () {
        var estadoDoCheck = $(this).prop('checked');
        if(estadoDoCheck == true) {


            id = $(this).attr('iddoemail');
            ArmazenaIds.push(id);
            alert(ArmazenaIds);

        }

    });
    console.log(ArmazenaIds);
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajaxDoEnvioMensagem.php',
        type:'post',
        data:ArmazenaIds,
        beforeSend:function() {
            alert('carregando');
```

Queria saber como posso enviar esse array com todos os dados dentro para o ajaxDoEnvioMensagem.php e conseguir recebê-los no php;

Meu objetivo é pegar este dados , receber no enviomensagem.php e logo após chamar o método php do objetos.php;
[image: AQUI EU QUERO RECEBER O VETOR JAVASCRIPT NO PHP]

Answer (score 0):

Falta uma pequena alteração no campo `data` passado como parametro para a função `$.ajax`:

```
<script>
    var ArmazenaIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    $.ajax({
    url:'ajaxDoEnvioMensagem.php',
    type:'post',
    data: {ids: ArmazenaIds},
    beforeSend:function() {
            alert('carregando');
    },
    success: function(dados){
        document.write(dados);
    }

    });
</script>
```

No campo data você pode passar um objeto com quantos atributos desejar. Tipo:

```
data: {campo1: [elemento1, elemento2], campo2: string}
```

Criei um novo vetor e a função success somente para testar. Um codigo php similar a esse é capaz de ler os dados enviados:

```
<?php
$ids = $_POST['ids'];

foreach($ids as $indice => $chave){
  echo $indice . ' => ' . $chave . '<br>';
}
```